# jQuery ajax select onChange update input field value with database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

i can't figure it out  My goal is after the user changed the value of the dropdown box my input field (f_project_straat) changes to the correct value retrieved from the php file.

i logged it and i get the correct values back but it only change after i refresh the page (f5) what i wish to have that i dont need to refresh the page.

i have a dropdown box and a input field a function and a diffrent php file.

**Dropdown box & input field**

```
        <div id="fc_opdrachtgever_id" class="at_e_f_container">
        <div id="fn_opdrachtgever_id" class="at_e_fieldname">
            Opdrachtgever *
        </div>
        <div id="fe_opdrachtgever_id" class="at_e_fieldvalue">
            <select name="f_opdrachtgever_id" id="f_opdrachtgever_id" onchange="showUser(this.value)">>
                [var.opdrachtgever;htmlconv=no]
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fc_project_straat" class="at_e_f_container">
        <div id="fn_project_straat" class="at_e_fieldname">
            <span>Project straat * </span>
        </div>
        <div id="fe_project_straat" class="at_e_fieldvalue">
            <input class="formfield" name="f_project_straat" id="f_project_straat" type="var" size=50 maxlength=150  value="[var.currentstreet]">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**I made the function like this :**

```
  $('#f_opdrachtgever_id').on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this).val();
    console.log(select)
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getadres.php",
    data: {
      id: select
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#f_project_straat').text(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
  })
```

**Finally i have made a php function to get**

```
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . CURRENTTABLE. " WHERE id = $id";
 $rs = DBExecute($sql );
                if ($rs){
                    if (!$rs->EOF){
                        $street = $rs->fields('street');
                        $_SESSION['s_street'] = $street ;
                        $GLOBALS['currentstreet']=$_SESSION['s_street'];
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You call this: `$('#f_project_straat').text(msg);` but your PHP code doesn't output anything. All it does is set the `$_SESSION` variable. You need to `echo` the new value. And use `$('#f_project_straat').val(msg);`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG i completely looked over it